# std::vector<std::vector<float>> in header file throws error LNK1120

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, c++17

I want to include my own header file but vector< vector < float > > throws an error

matrix.cpp

```
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> d_data = { {} })
    {
        data = d_data;
    }

};
```

matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>


class Matrix {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> d_data = { {} });
};

#endif
```

matrixc++.cpp

```
#include <C:\Users\Matteo\source\repos\matrixc++\matrixc++\Matrix.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    Matrix abc({{1,2},{2,1}});
    return 0;
}
```

Following error occurs :

> matrixc++.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Matrix::Matrix(class std::vector<class std::vector<float,class std::allocator >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<float,class std::allocator > > >)" (??0Matrix@@QEAA@V?$vector@V?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main

Comment: Content of matrix.cpp is suspicious it should be something like `#inlcude "matrix.h " Matrix::Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> d_data) : data(std::move(d_data)) {}`, instead of redefining the class (ODR violation).

Comment: The code has two different definitions of `Matrix`, one in `matrix.cpp` and one in `matrix.h`. Get rid of one of them.

Comment: Define the class once, in one file. Don't copy and paste it more than once.

Comment: Why are you declaring the `Matrix` class both in matrix.h and in matrix.cpp ?

Comment: As a side note, please avoid to put absolute file paths in `#include`. Usually, relative paths from current source file work out of the box. And you should prefer forward slashes `/` to backslashes `\ ` for portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that you've more or less copy pasted the class definition to the source file `matrix.cpp`. That is, you have defined the class `Matrix` twice. Once in the header and second time in the source file.

To **solve** this just provide the implementation for the constructor `Matrix::Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>>)` inside the source file as shown below:

**matrix.cpp**

```
#include <C:\Users\Matteo\source\repos\matrixc++\matrixc++\Matrix.h>

//implement only the constructor
Matrix::Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> d_data): data(d_data)
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ use constructor initializer list
{
    
}
```

**matrix.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>


class Matrix {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> d_data = { {} });
};

#endif
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/uK4ZBr0Frr)